# How to share an image on Facebook from a desktop application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a desktop application that generates an image. I want to share this image to Facebook. I *don't* want to implement the whole workflow, the login dialog etc. (and even if I did, the Facebook Web Sharing documentation doesn't seem to cover regular desktop apps so I wouldn't know how to).

I've already uploaded the image to cloud hosting and have a direct link. Let's assume there is a default browser properly configured in the operating system, and the user is logged into FB in that browser. Is it possible to trigger sharing the image by simply requesting a specific Facebook URL via this browser?

If not, what options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4#redirect) is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Windws 10 and you can facebook app in your pc,You can easily share pics by clicking "Share Button".
if your not using latest windows 10 ,You need to install third part app for easily sharing pictures to facebook,
You can read more about these apps in here

[List of apps](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/facebook-desktop-applications/)

http://asmhijas.com/

Comment: Thank you, but I'd prefer a library that I can integrate into my app, or even better - simply by using a browser.